# Obtener promedio y retornar True, False

Tags: python

Estoy tratando que este programa obtenga el valor promedio para la lista asociada a cada una de las keys, si el valor del promedio es mayor a 61, entonces sobrescribir por medio del uso de condiciones el valor en el diccionario est_30_Aprueba del mismo key con el valor booleano True cuando hice el promedio me da el promedio de todas las keys no de una en especifico

```
 est_30 = { 20118: [100,70,80],
           20119: [90,100,90],
           20120: [85,30,40],
           20122: [00,98,90],
           20289: [10,67,50],
           20937: [17,14,58]
          }




est_30_Aprueba = { 20118: False,
                   20119: False,
                   20120: False,
                   20122: False,
                   20289: False,
                   20937: False,
                  }

est_30_Aprueba = { 20118: True,
                   20119: True,
                   20120: True,
                   20122: True,
                   20289: True,
                   20937: True,
                  }



in2 = int(input("Ingrese #carné para conocer si aprobó: "))
dato2 = est_30_Aprueba.get(in2)
print(dato2)

import statistics
mean = statistics.mean(est_30)
```

Answer (score 0):

puedes usar la consulta al diccionario como parámetro del objeto "mean", de la forma:

mean = statistics.mean(est_30.get(in2))

Resta utilizar unos condicionales para actualizar los valores del diccionario con valores booleanos de la forma:

```
if mean >= 61:
    est_30_Aprueba[in2] = True

else:
    est_30_Aprueba[in2] = False
```

Código completo:

```
est_30 = { 20118: [100,70,80],
           20119: [90,100,90],
           20120: [85,30,40],
           20122: [00,98,90],
           20289: [10,67,50],
           20937: [17,14,58]
          }

est_30_Aprueba = { 20118: False,
                   20119: False,
                   20120: False,
                   20122: False,
                   20289: False,
                   20937: False,
                  }


import statistics

in2 = int(input("Ingrese #carné para conocer si aprobó: "))
mean = statistics.mean(est_30.get(in2))

if mean >= 61:
    est_30_Aprueba[in2] = True

else:
    est_30_Aprueba[in2] = False

dato2 = est_30_Aprueba.get(in2)
print(dato2)
```

- 

Cuando el código es ejecutado se crea un objeto "mean" conteniendo el promedio de la lista que es pasada como un parámetro, en caso de querer hacer varias consultas sin tener que volver a ejecutar el código, es necesario adjuntar la creacion del objeto a un ciclo.

Comment: Gracias amigo me has salvado, perdona quitarte tu tiempo ;)

Answer (score 0):

No te valdría en vez de modificar el diccionario `est_30_Aprueba` y luego modificarlo, crearlo directamente?

```
import statistics

aprueba = lambda x: statistics.mean(x)> 61  #Devuelve True si x>61 si no False
est_30_Aprueba = {a:aprueba(est_30[a])  for a in est_30}  #Crea el diccionario.
```

Con esto tienes por ejemplo (Tu pondrías `est_30_Aprueba[nombre_de_tu_variable]`):

```
print(est_30_Aprueba[20119])  #True
print(est_30_Aprueba[20937])  #False
```

Si no necesitas el diccionario `est_30_Aprueba` para nada, puedes responder a la pregunta de si han aprobado consultando directamente `est_30`:

```
print(True if statistics.mean(est_30[20937]) > 61 else False)  #Devuelve False
```